# How do I compare two files in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to compare two files, one is a fixture (source of truth) and the other is downloaded (to be tested).
I would usually use something like:

```
cy.fixture("file1.txt").then((fixture) => {
                cy.readFile("file2.txt").then((download) => {
                    expect(fixture).to.eq(download);
```

However there is currently a [bug](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25443) in cypress where the cy.readFile enters an endless loop when using an assert.

Is there a work around for this or another way to compare these two files? Thanks

Comment: I'm not reproducing it - is there a largish size to the files? The issue states jpg and tiff, but I used txt as that's what you have.

Comment: Used both same files (test passes) and different files (test fails correctly).

Comment: I am comparing to html files and using Base64. I think it is the size of the files I am comparing as using smaller html files works fine. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be due to trying to log a large comparison to the Cypress log.

You can try using a different comparison method that does not show the file contents:

```js
cy.fixture('file1.txt').then(fixture => {
  cy.readFile('cypress/downloads/file2.txt').then(download => {
    // expect(fixture).to.eq(download)
    assert(fixture === download, 'files are matching').to.eq(true)
  })
})
```

This will give you a simpler log entry which hopefully does not hang the browser.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work, I do think its the size of the files I am comparing. 
Also I think the assert style used here would be `assert.equal(fixture, download, 'files are matching')` just for anyone else looking. Thanks